# Basket suddenly appears empty

Tags: shopping-cart

a few customers complained that they addes products to theri basket and once they pressed PROCEED TO CHECKOUT they got the messsage
'your basket is empty'

does anyone know why this may happen?
does the system crash??

thanks
Stef

Answer (score 1):

It seems some code level issue is there. But before that you can try below things in your hand:

1. Clear all the caches from System->Cache Management
2. Check if recently you installed any extension. Try to disable it.
3. If this is happening with some products then see that product configurations in backend.